# Echo server built with Netcat and FIFO fails when used with rev

Tags: bash, shell, unix, netcat

I'm playing around with Netcat, and I've successfully made an echo server like this:

```
mkfifo fifo
cat fifo | nc -l 3000 > fifo
```

Next, I'd like to apply some transformation to the data before it's echoed back:

```
cat fifo | nc -l 3000 | rev > fifo
# Or:
cat fifo | rev | nc -l 3000 > fifo
```

But neither of the above works. The same happens when I use any text-tranforming program, not just `rev`. But if I replace `rev` with `cat`, it works again:

```
cat fifo | nc -l 3000 | cat > fifo
```

This leads me to believe there's something special about how `cat` uses standard in and standard out. (As compared to `rev`, `tr`, and other similar text-transforming programs.)

What's going on here? Why does inserting `rev` into the pipeline break the echo server? Is `cat` indeed special, and if so, how?

Comment: rev cannot operate on streams directly due to the nature of it unless it builds a copy of the entire file in memory on the fly then reads it back from the end

Comment: It's not an answer, but want to see something cool:  nc -l 3000 < fifo | bash  > fifo 2>&1 . it works like a pseudo telnet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to buffering. `glibc` automatically buffers output when stdout is not a terminal. 
efficiency.

You can see the same effect in your terminal where `rev` reverses each line as you type it, while `rev | cat` does not.

To fix it, you have to get your command to not buffer. GNU has a `stdbuf` tool for doing this for arbitrary commands:

```
cat fifo | nc -l 3000 | stdbuf -o 0 rev > fifo
```

The interactive command scripting tool `expect` also comes with an `unbuffer` command to do the same.

Buffering is only efficient when combining multiple small writes into a large one. Programs that just copy from one place to another (like `cat` and `dd`) don't benefit from buffering and therefore don't do it.

Comment: Reading up on `stdbuf`, I see that `cat` is indeed special. But even so, why doesn't `rev` ever process its input buffer and flush to `fifo`? As far as I can tell, there are newlines in the stream I'm feeding it. Shouldn't each complete line make it all the way through the pipe?

Comment: It does, but you have to input enough data. On my Ubuntu system, `rev`'s buffer is 4kb. Line buffering is only used when stdout is a terminal, which is not the case here.

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood. I thought you were saying that `rev` didn't buffer at all. When in fact the problem is that it does; the buffer is just bigger than I need it to be. What I want, then, is line buffering. Makes sense.